# Outlook OfficeJS API context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync method does not return body randomly

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We have not been able to identify a definite pattern but the [body.getAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-1.8#getasync-coerciontype--callback-) method does not return the mail body randomly.We started noticing this behaviour after January 8th 2020.This behaviour is exhibited under:

- Clients: OWA and Desktop (Windows Outlook 2016, 2019 and 2013)
- The mails affected are not system mails

EDIT: Added requested code snippet

```js
  item.body.getAsync("html", (mailBody) => {
        mail.body = someFunc(mailBody.value);
        if (!mailBody.value) {
          console.log("Fetching Text content");
          return getBodyTextContent(item.body, mail)
          .then((m) => resolve(m))
          .catch((e) => reject(e));
        }
        return resolve(mail);
   });
```

**Reference**

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-1.8#getasync-coerciontype--callback-

Comment: Since you are experiencing this across multiple clients, would it be possible to take a look at a snippet of your code? Do you get any error when the body is not returned? Or is the returned body just an empty string?

Comment: The returned body is null

Comment: In your code snippet, is the behavior you're seeing that the condition is skipped (because `!mailBody.value` is true)? Does the getAsync function return any error (it would be in the mailBody object)?